# Raspberry: No module named flask_api

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

Im developing some simple Post/Get scripts that i want to run on my Raspberry, but im new to Webdevelopment and python as well.

On my Windows machine i have been using Pycharm and Postman to develop and test the basics of the app (everything works fine here), and next i simply cloned the repository to the raspberry.

I installed the packages
`sudo pip3 intall Flask` and `sudo pip3 install FLASK-API`

if i would run them again, the terminal gives me back a `requirement already satisfied`, that i assume is confirmation the package was installed correctly.

However, when i run the python scripts on the raspberry its giving me this stupid error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FlaskRun01.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_api import FlaskAPI
ImportError: No module named flask_api
```

For information; line 3 in the py code is simply just `from flask_api import FlaskAPI`

Any idea's why it doesnt want to run and cant find the right module ?

**EDIT - Solved**

leaving the solution here for future reference and anyone looking for the same issue. On the raspberry i had to run `python3 myScript.py` instead of `python myScript.py`

Comment: You are installing these packages for python3 when you use *pip3* instead of *pip* on  most of debian based distros. You are running the project with *python3*, aren't you?

Comment: ooooh stupid me! i needed to execute the py script with "python3 myScript.py" instead of "python myScript.py".. oops
thanx @Buğraİşgüzar

Answer (score 1):

On most of linux distros and windows *pip* and *pip3* is not same thing (for example, in manjaro they are same thing, because manjaro using python3 as default python version). So you need to be sure you are using correct version of python and pip.

For example, if you install a package with *pip3* and run your script with *python foo.py* it won't run as you expected. Because *python* (equals to *python2* in your case) can't find packages which one installed for *python3* with **pip3**.